# Disable use of UEFI OEM Key

Tags: windows-update, uefi, windows-activation, oem

I am having a fun issue on some laptops with windows 10, when installing from my image everything works great, windows is activated with the license included, office and all other programs are activated, machines are joined to the domain. However, after installing a feature update (1703>1809 for example) windows re-activates with the OEM key that is stored in the UEFI. I did some testing and if I switch the from UEFI to Legacy, it will prevent this at least on the machines that its an issue on, but that isn't a proper fix.This only happens on machines that had an OEM key, all other machines behave as expected.

I was wondering if there is an item that can be added to the image to prevent this, other than switching to legacy, or just scripting all the OEM machines to re-license with the proper key.

Comment: How are you pushing out the update?

Comment: As of now software center is pushing the update out, I am unsure how this package was built. (yay separation of duties). I haven't tried updating through windows automatic update service. However, after updating my image everything still installs fine so I know its at least not an issue with just the 1809 update.

Comment: If you are using Software Center to handle updates then Windows Update should efficiently be disabled.  You have to find out how the image being pushed was created, it sounds like the problem is the image being used, is the reason for your problems.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking to, I'm pretty sure the issue is the media being used contains media for multiple versions of windows, I'll make some media that contains strictly a single version of windows and test. If that is the issue I'll update this.

Comment: Unless you are doing a clean install through Software Center it should matter if there are multiple versions on the ISO.